# Conformally mapping quadrants throu powers

Tags: complex-analysis

This is the problem.

Map the quadrants $q_1 \cup q_3 \cup q_4$ in the complex plane (where the index is the quadrant, i.e. $q_1$ is the first quadrant and so on) to the upper half plane.

The answer, given without justification, is the map $C: z \mapsto z^{2/3}$. 
This really doesn't gel well in my head. Isn't the idea that $C$ will multiply the arguments by $\frac{2}{3}$?

Question 1: For $z \in q_4$, we have $arg \ z > \frac{3\pi}{2}$, thus, for such $z$, we have $arg \ C(z) > \pi $, so we're hitting the third quadrant. How can this be right??

Question 2: if I consider the points in $q_3, q_4$ with negative arguments, then 
mutliplying the argument by $\frac{2}{3}$ with surely not make me leave $q_4$. What is the proper way of considering these arguments, as $[0,2\pi)$ or as $(-\pi, \pi]$? The mapping $C$ above seems to map differently depending on how I calculate the angles.

Question 3: If the above map $C$ really is incorrect, what is the correct mapping that sends $q_1 \cup q_3 \cup q_4$ to the upper half plane?

What's a good $\textit{intuitive}$ picture to have?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before applying the conformal map, we can describe $q_1\cup q_3\cup q_4$ as the set of $z$ such that $-\pi\leq\arg z\leq\pi/2$. Applying the map $z\mapsto z^{2/3}$, understood as the *principal branch*, multiplies arguments by $2/3$, so the image of the quadrants is the set of $z$ such that $-\frac23\pi\leq\arg z\leq\frac13\pi$. This is a half plane, but rotated by $-2/3\pi$ radians; to complete the transformation to the *upper* half plane, we would need to apply the map $z\mapsto e^{2\pi i/3}z$.

It would seem, then, that the answer is wrong. However, there is a more generous interpretation under which it is right. There are two other branches of the map $z\mapsto z^{2/3}$, given by $re^{i\theta}\mapsto r^{2/3}e^{2i\theta/3}\omega$ and $re^{i\theta}\mapsto r^{2/3}e^{2i\theta/3}\omega^2$, where $\omega=e^{2\pi i/3}$ is a third root of unity. The second of these branches *does* map $q_1\cup q_3\cup q_4$ conformally to the upper half plane.

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thanks! :)

Comment: Btw, at the end of the first paragraph, you mean of course the map $z \mapsto e^{2\pi i /3} z ^{2/3}$, yes?

Comment: What I meant to say is that you apply the transformation $z\mapsto e^{2\pi i/3}z$ *after* the transformation $z\mapsto z^{2/3}$. The composite of the two transformations would indeed be $z\mapsto e^{2\pi i/3}z^{2/3}$.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that $z^{2/3} = (re^{i\arg z})^{2/3} = r^{2/3}e^{i2\arg z/3},$ where $\arg$ is the principal value argument, the answer given is wrong. It should be $e^{i2\pi/3}z^{2/3}.$